# Masonry js is messing with the Bootstrap tab function

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, tabs, jquery-masonry, masonry

I am using the Bootstrap tab function with Desandro's Masonry, and the problem is that when I load the page, it starts on the first tab for half a second, then jumps to the tab with the Masonry.
I am guessing that I could fix this with some scripting, but I am too new to js/jquery to figure it out.

I tried changing the order of the script code, because it looks to me like the page loads and then the Masonry script happens and forces its tab to the active state. But it still happens no matter what order the code is in.

Specifically what I need is either for someone to point out a mistake I overlooked or give me some pointers on how to make the page stay on the first tab when it loads.

I have included my html and js controls here, but I also made a fiddle with the full code at http://jsfiddle.net/jccarter1990/o15e98ts/3/

Thanks in advance

```html
<ul class="nav nav-pills" role="tablist" id="myTab">
  <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="#page-one" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Cover Letter</a></li>
  <li role="presentation"><a href="#page-two" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Features</a></li>
  <li role="presentation"><a href="#page-three" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Gallery</a></li>
 </ul>

<div class="tab-content">

<div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane active"  id="page-one">Cover Letter</div>
  
<div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane"  id="page-two">Features</div>
  
<div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane"  id="page-three">
  <div class="masonry js-masonry" >
  <div class="item"><img class="thumbnail" src="img/paigeJohnLasVegas.jpg"></div>
  <div class="item"><img class="thumbnail" src="img/engagementsCloseUp.jpg"></div>
  <div class="item"><img class="thumbnail" src="img/jimmyJohns.jpg"></div>
  <div class="item"><img class="thumbnail" src="img/paigeNinjaTurtle.jpg"></div>
  <div class="item"><img class="thumbnail" src="img/sprayPaintSid.jpg"></div>
    </div>  
  </div>
```

```js
<script>
 var container = document.querySelector('.masonry');
  var msnry;
  // initialize Masonry after all images have loaded
  imagesLoaded( container, function() {
  msnry = new Masonry( container );
  });
 var container = document.querySelector('.masonry');
  var msnry = new Masonry( container, {
    // options
    columnWidth: 200,
    itemSelector: '.masonry.item'
  });
 
 $('#myTab a').click(function (e) {
  e.preventDefault()
  $(this).tab('show')
})

 $(function () {
  $('#myTab a[href="#page-one"]').tab('show')
  $('#myTab a[href="#page-two"]').tab('show')
  $('#myTab a[href="#page-three"]').tab('show')
 })

 
</script>
```

Comment: So you don't have a fiddle or bin but you want people to install all this stuff and then figure out a solution for free? Make a fiddle or bin with all the scripts and initializations.

Comment: thanks, im very new to this. i have included a link to my fiddle, which should have everything you need

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/tmtwfxcj/

Answer (score 1):

UPDATED ANSWER: Set your first tab and panel  as the active tab:

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/macsupport/p6Ltc7co/2/)

```
 <div class="container navigation"> <span class="nt-name">John Carter</span>

 <br>   <span class="nt-title">Professional Portfolio</span>

 <ul class="nav nav-pills" role="tablist" id="myTab">
    <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="#page-one" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Cover Letter</a>

    </li>
    <li role="presentation"><a href="#page-two" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Features</a>

    </li>
    <li role="presentation"><a href="#page-three" class="active" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Gallery</a>

    </li>
</ul>
 </div>
 <div class="tab-content">
<div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane active" id="page-one">
    <div class="container">
            <h1>Cover Letter</h1>

    </div>
</div>
<div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="page-two">
    <div class="container">
         <h1>Features</h1>

    </div>
 </div>
  <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="page-three">
    <div class="container">
            <h1>Gallery</h1>

    </div>
    <div class="masonry js-masonry">
        <div class="item">
            <img class="thumbnail" src="img/paigeJohnLasVegas.jpg">
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <img class="thumbnail" src="img/engagementsCloseUp.jpg">
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <img class="thumbnail" src="img/jimmyJohns.jpg">
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <img class="thumbnail" src="img/paigeNinjaTurtle.jpg">
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <img class="thumbnail" src="img/sprayPaintSid.jpg">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Change your script to just this:

```
//bootstrap tab function
$('#myTab a').click(function (e) {
e.preventDefault()
$(this).tab('show')
})
```

Leave out:

BTW, you don't have to include the bootstrap.js for tabs in your jsfiddle if you check the box to include Bootstrap, it includes the js. If you have other js to include, like masonry.js, add them using external resources instead of pasting them into the script panel This will make it much easier fior people to see the relevant code.

Comment: I don't want the third tab to show up first though. The problem is that it's going to the third tab even when the first one is set to active. I want a way for the Masonry on tab 3 to load properly, but for the page to start on tab 1 like normal. But thanks for the tip on Fiddle, that was very helpful.